# Nagios/Icinga Checks running for long time

Tags: nagios, icinga

I am currently running `Icinga1` to monitor around ~6000 services.

On the Icinga dashboard, I see that the average check time is ~ 300 s, which means some of my checks are running slow. Unfortunately , because there are 6000 checks I don't have a way to figure out all the checks that are running for more than a sec.

Is there a way to figure out the checks which run for more than a certain duration(say 5 sec) either from the classic UI or from the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the wiki - performance tuning with Icinga1 is a big topic over there.

https://wiki.icinga.org/display/howtos/Identify+long+lasting+checks

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that it using the icinga.cfg you can write host and service check performance data to files in custom formats.

- Documentation for [host performance data](http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/configmain.html#configmain-host_perfdata_file)
- Documentation for [service performance data](http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/configmain.html#configmain-service_perfdata_file)

You can also setup pnp4nagios to read this info and convert it into graphical reports.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using "crontab" to make the checks on different times to lower the use of the system.

Read more about crontab here - http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference